# Writing a simple CPLEX model

Tags: java, cplex, constraint-programming

I'm trying to write a CPLEX model that reflects this set of constraints:

```
x, y, z in { 1, 2, 3 }
constraint C1: AllDiff(x,y,z)
constraint C2: z == x + 2y
constraint C3: y < x
constraint C4: z == 2x
```

The goal of the model is to find an appropriate value for z that adheres to the constraints. This of course is impossible because constraints C1 and C2 together make the model infeasible. There is no value of z that fits these constraints. I want to design this model in Java and then run the cpoptimizer command "display conflict" on the model to see if it finds the C1 C2 conflict. I've started with this

```
IloCP cp = new IloCP();
IloIntVar numSet = cp.intVar(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, "numSet");
```

But I don't know where to go from here or if this is even correct. How do you state that x, y, z are all in this set and that they all have to be different?

I've started writing the model but I'm a little stuck as I've never written a CPLEX model before. I'm not sure how to write these constraints in a way that CPLEX understands.

Answer (score 0):

in the example teambuilding.java you may read

```
        IloIntVar[] allVars = cp.intVarArray(nbPersons);
        int s = 0;
        int w;
        int p;
        for (w = 0; w < nbTeams; ++w) {
            for (p = 0; p < teamSize; ++p) {
                allVars[s] = groups[w][p];
                ++s;
            }
        }
        cp.add(cp.allDiff(allVars));
```